# Limiting a for loop to a certain number of times for a fantasy football draft

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, dom

Trying to make a fantasy football app for a side project and don't have the best javascript experience. Been able to get the players to a drafted column but can't limit the number of people drafted (5 in this example) or from letting the player only be drafted once.

```
    <div class="main">
        <div class="Quarterbacks">
        <h2>Quarterbacks (5 spots, 50pts)</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Dak Prescott</button></td>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Tom Brady</button></td>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Patrick Maholmes</button></td>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Trevor Lawerence</button></td>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Justin Fields</button></td>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Phillip Rivers</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Jared Goff</button></td>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Carson Wentz</button></td>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Matt Ryan</button></td>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Kurt Cousins</button></td>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Dree Brews</button></td>
                <td><button class="qb-btn">Sam Darnold</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
```

```
<div class="drafted-qb">
<h2> Drafted Quarterbacks</h2>
</div>
```

```
const qbButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('qb-btn')
for (let i = 0; i <  qbButtons.length; i++) {
    let button = qbButtons[i]
    button.addEventListener('click', addQb)
}

function addQb(event){
   let button = event.target
   let quarterbacks = button.parentElement
   let players = quarterbacks.getElementsByClassName('qb-btn')[0].innerText
   console.log(players)
   addQbToDrafted(players)
}


function addQbToDrafted(players) {
    let qbSpot =  document.createElement('div')
    qbSpot.innerText = players
    let draftedQb = document.getElementsByClassName('drafted-qb')[0]
    draftedQb.append(qbSpot)
}
```

Comment: Where and what is the problem? what is the expected output?

Comment: I want to be able to add only 5 quarterbacks to to "drafted-qb"  with no repeats

Comment: I posted a solution that is a bit different than yours, but it does what you were trying to do. Along with that, it's also responsive and adjusts to screen changes using flex's wrap.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var players = ["Dak Prescott", "Tom Brady", "Patrick Maholmes", "Trevor Lawerence", "Justin Fields", "Phillip Rivers", "Jared Goff", "Carson Wentz", "Matt Ryan", "Kurt Cousins", "Dree Brews", "Sam Darnold"]
var draftLimit = 5

for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
  var player = players[i]
  var input = document.createElement("input")
  input.type = "checkbox"
  input.id = player
  document.body.children[0].appendChild(input)
  var label = document.createElement("label")
  label.for = player
  label.innerText = player
  document.body.children[0].appendChild(label)
  document.body.children[0].appendChild(document.createElement("br"))

  input.addEventListener("change", function(evt) {
    numInputsChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length
    document.getElementsByClassName("diagnose-errors")[0].remove()

    if (numInputsChecked < draftLimit) {
      var div = document.createElement("div")
      div.style.backgroundColor = "red"
      div.style.color = "white"
      div.innerText = "Please choose " + (draftLimit - numInputsChecked) + " more quarterback(s)."
      div.className = "diagnose-errors"
      document.body.children[0].appendChild(div)
    } else if (numInputsChecked > draftLimit) {
      var div = document.createElement("div")
      div.style.backgroundColor = "red"
      div.style.color = "white"
      div.innerText = "Please remove " + (numInputsChecked - draftLimit) + " quarterback(s) from your selection."
      div.className = "diagnose-errors"
      document.body.children[0].appendChild(div)
    } else {
      var button = document.createElement("button")
      button.innerText = "It's showtime!"
      button.className = "diagnose-errors"
      document.body.children[0].appendChild(button)
    }
    inputsChecked = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
    checkedNames = []
    for (var i = 0; i < inputsChecked.length; i++) {
      checkedNames.push(inputsChecked[i].id)
    }
    document.getElementsByClassName("drafted")[0].innerText = checkedNames.join("\n")
  })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="display:flex;flex-wrap:wrap;align-items:stretch">
  <div style="flex:1;">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Quarterbacks</h1>
    <div class="diagnose-errors"></div>
  </div>
  <div style="flex:1;">
    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Drafted</h1>
    <div class="drafted"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```